# Alternative to a bunch of preg_replace

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace, embed

Currently I have a custom url syntax that I use to save urls from input. Then I use output buffering to fetch the whole document at the end of execution and replace url syntaxes with anchor tags. But I also have an image syntax that converts image links from input to image tags, as well as youtube tags that convert youtube links to embedded videos.

Long story short

`[url]http://www.somesite.com/[my site]`
becomes
`<a href='http://www.somesite.com/'>my site</a>`

`[img]http://www.somesite.com/image.jpg[/img]`
becomes
`<img src='http://www.somesite.com/image.jpg'/>`

You get the point. It's kind of starting to bother me because I know that `preg_replace` is known to have an impact on performance and running it multiple times on a roughly 10,000 character long string
( average html document length for my site ) is really not good. I would also like to implement auto-embedding for more websites, and using my current algorithm would mean that I will have to add a new `preg_replace` for each site, which is ridiculous. I'm looking for advice on how to implement this functionality. Thanks!

EDIT:

I think I didn't express myself clear enough. I am looking for a way to match all of my components with a single parse of the document string. For example when you go to buy groceries you don't go picking up tomatoes, bring them home then go again to pick up cucumbers. You do all the things simultaneously, that's what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: @tereško doesn't bbcode work the same way my thing works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you want to skip using preg_* (although it's the obviuos choice) because of performance considerations.

If this has become an issue, then you might have to change much more (1*) than your replacement strategy.

> long story short
>
> [url]http://www.somesite.com/[my site]

is not such a short story:
[my site] can only be formated if there is prior knowledge of [url], and everything in between (of variable length) must be concatenated between `<a href="` and `"`. [my site] which is of vaiable length as well must be extracted and concatenated between `>` and `</a>`.

what this all meeans is that, apart from using regexp, you may have to do **multiple operations** (`str_replace`) on your string which means **multiple *secuential* passes** which may interfere with one another or other content.

My long story short...

This is what regexps are for, use these wonderfull tools at your disposal. If you begin to have performance issues because of document length, then consider other alternatives

- breaking up the content and serving it in pieces, a la page1, page2 type
- if your content requires no further editing, save formatted and let it passthrough unescaped on output
- upgrading from your current hosting provider
- changing the ***current format*** the content is being saved in (1*). Oh, lala! that might be a whole project in itself
- (someone else might want to chime in with some more experience)

Comment: What I actually realized is that I don't need to search the whole document, only user input saved in databases and stuff... One of these moments that just makes you think "Am I retarded?".. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

From php.net about preg_replace:

> If both pattern and replacement parameters are arrays, each pattern
>   will be replaced by the replacement counterpart.

So:

```
preg_replace( array('pattern_for_url', 'pattern_for_img'), array('replace_for_url', 'replace_for_img', $document_content) );
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: Well that will just save me some typing but it will still run preg_replace multiple times :/

Comment: Why you will still run preg_replace multiple times? You can match all your components in one preg.